# How to design a RESTful HTTP gateway for a protocol that requires persistent connections?

Tags: rest, gateway

I'm working with a persistent client/server protocol and I need to design a RESTful gateway. I don't have a lot of experience designing REST interfaces and I don't understand how I should handle (in a RESTful way) the session IDs needed to maintain persistent connections on the server and how I should represent server state as resources.

I'm asking this because I don't want to end-up with a RPC-ish result that looks "RESTful".

Problem specific context: I want to improve the existing ZooKeeper REST gateway to support ephemeral nodes and watches. An ephemeral node exists while the client is connected to the server.

Thanks.

Comment: I would like to set a bounty for this question. How can I do this?

Comment: I guess you can only set a bounty if you don't accept an answer within a few days.

Comment: Why was this made a community wiki?

Comment: That was an error. Is it possible to change it back to a regular question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way in which I've done this in the past follows a "ticket" or "receipt" pattern. The REST service accepts requests for a resource (a report name, a znode, etc.) and returns a ticket. This ticket (usually a UUID or something similar) can be used to represent a session. Subsequent requests use this ticket to check on the status of their requests. To ensure proper expirey of tickets, one of two cases occurs; you can time out tickets or, upon receiving a result, the client must provide an ACK (acknowledgment) back to the service.

ex.

Request: GET /zookeeper/znode/ephemeral/foo
Response: 1234-1234-1234-1234

Request: GET /zookeeper/status/1234-1234-1234-1234
Response: WORKING (or UNAVAILABLE or BLOCKED or NOTREADY or FAILED...)

Request: GET /zookeeper/status/1234-1234-1234-1234
Response: ACQUIRED (or AVAILABLE or OK or SUCCESS or some value(s)...)

Request: GET /zookeeper/acknowledge/1234-1234-1234-1234
Response: OK (or UNKNOWN TICKET, etc.)

Interesting manageability messages:

Request: GET /zookeeper/sessions (or /tickets)
Response: [ 1234, 5668, ... ]

Request: GET /zookeeper/kill/
Response: OK (or UNKNOWN or FAILED...)

This has worked very, very well. This does mean, however the REST service is stateful which makes things like load balancing trickier. I've used a protocol that ensures a server ID is returned with each response and if the client receives a different server ID and an UNKNOWN ticket, you assume the service you were talking to has died and start over. This implies sticky load balancing (i.e. round-robin wouldn't work here). The REST service needs to be multi-threaded to support performing these requests in parallel and provide access to a ticket database (usually in memory, sync'd hashtable data structure) as well as a session / ticket timeout thread.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast. I was thinking about a similar solution.